# How to copy columns from cell arrays to create another cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a 1 by 4 cell array ( 1 row and 4 columns). Every single column of that cell array contains a 4 by 4 matrix. I only want to copy the first, second and, the third row of the 4th column of every 4 by 4 matrix and create another 1 by 4 cell array which is 3 by 1  (3 rows and 1 column elements copied). I was wondering what is an efficient method of doing this?

```
for i=1:1:number_links
    for j=1:1:3
          O{1,i}(j,4)=T{1,i}(j,4);
   end
end
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I just did, but it is giving me a 3 by 4 matrix. I am looking for a 3 by 1 matrix in every single 1 by 4 cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your code. Here is an example. I created a 1 by 4 cell array named `c`. Each cell is `rand(4)` (4 by 4 matrix of random numbers). My method is to use a `for` loop and change each cell by `c{1,i} = c{1,i}(1:3,4)`. Here `c{1,i}(1:3,4)` gives the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd row of 4th column.

```
% create 1 by 4 cell array. Each cell is a 4 by 4 matrix
c = cell(1,4);
for i = 1:4
    c{1,i} = rand(4);
end
disp(c)

% change 1 by 4 cell array. Each cell is a 3 by 1 matrix
for i = 1:4
    c{1,i} = c{1,i}(1:3,4);
end
disp(c)
```

Output:

```
[4x4 double]    [4x4 double]    [4x4 double]    [4x4 double]

[3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]
```

Answer (score 2):

[Banghua gives a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057094/7328782). But it is possible to hide the loop using `cellfun`. I'm not sure if it actually is cleaner than a plain old loop, but it is nice to know about the possibilities:

```
O = cellfun(@(x)x(1:3,4),T,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Here we're using an anonymous function `@(x)x(1:3,4)`, which is applied to each element `T{1,i}`. That is, `O{1,i} = T{1,i}(1:3,4)`, just as in Banghua's answer.